# Live streaming video in html 5 - What is required from server to stream and let other domains acsess that streams?

Tags: video, html, streaming, live

Live streaming video in html 5 - what is required from server to stream and let other domains access that streams?

- any cross-domain-policy files?
- any special streaming servers technologies/requirements etc? (I want LIVE streaming NOT FILE streaming)? (like shoutcast or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened to [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol)?